# unable to show username in php login page

Tags: php, login-system

i am creating a login system for my website and unable to print out user name after the user logs in.

after verifying from the data base i have  done this:

```
  $_SESSION['userName'];
  $_SESSION['password'];
  header("location:success.php");
```

and this is the code to print user name in success.php file:

```
   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['userName']!='')
   {
    header("location:login_form.php");

    }
    else
    {
     echo '<h2>Successfully Login <br /> Welcome '.$userName.'</h2>';

     echo '<a href="logout.php"> Log Out</a>';
     }
```

but user name is not printed.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the `Location` header expects a full (absolute) URL.

Comment: @PeeHaa isn't it the case when you are working on external server??

Comment: No. The spec states that an absolute URL should be used.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
echo '<h2>Successfully Login <br /> Welcome '.$_SESSION['userName'].'</h2>';
```

And

```
if($_SESSION['userName']!='')
```

Should be

```
if($_SESSION['userName']=='')
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're not assigning the sessions to any values.

```
$_SESSION['userName'];
$_SESSION['password'];

header("location:success.php");
```

should be:

```
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'My Username';
$_SESSION['password'] = 'My Password';
header("location:success.php");
```

Secondly, you haven't defined the variable `$userName`. Change it to: `$_SESSION['userName']`.

On a side-note, you shouldn't store passwords in sessions, also, you should add `die()` or `exit()` after re-directing the user with `header()`.

**Edit:**

Just re-read your code. Although the answerers before me suggested you change this line:

```
if ($_SESSION['userName'] != '')
```

to:

```
if ($_SESSION['userName'] == '')
```

It's actually bad practice to use logical operators to check if sessions exist. The correct way would be to use the `isset()` function:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userName']))
```

Good luck!

Comment: if (array_key_exists('userName', $_SESSION)) is another possible check.

Comment: solved by using: echo '<h2>Successfully Login <br /> Welcome</h2>' .$userName and by if ($_SESSION['userName'] == '');

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if($_SESSION['userName']!='')
```

should be:

```
if($_SESSION['userName']=='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you omitted the code elsewhere, this variable isn't defined: `$userName`

You are missing defining it as a variable. Try:

```
$userName= $_SESSION['userName'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

Comment: I think you've got those assignments backwards.

Comment: @Sammitch Where else is $userName defined then?